# Автозум в yandex map api 2.1

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Собственно не пойму что делаю не так. 
НУжно сделать автозум.

Вот пример кода, который у меня работает.

```
ymaps.ready(function () {
        var myMap = new ymaps.Map('yamap', {
            center: [55.753215,37.622504],
            zoom: 10
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        });

    });


function setBounds() {    
        myMap.setBounds([ [55.142627,36.803259],  [56.021281,37.967682]], {checkZoomRange: true});
}
```

Карту генирирует, всё ок, но вот проблема в том что при выполнении myMap.setBounds пишет ошибку

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: myMap is not defined
```

Comment: у вас переменная myMap объявлена внутри ymaps.ready, а обращаетесь вы к этой переменной в другой функции, которая о myMap ничего не знает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var myMap;

ymaps.ready(function () {
        myMap = new ymaps.Map('yamap', {
            center: [55.753215,37.622504],
            zoom: 10
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        });

    });


function setBounds() {    
        myMap.setBounds([ [55.142627,36.803259],  [56.021281,37.967682]], {checkZoomRange: true});
}
```

Comment: Главное не забывать что функция-параметр `ymaps.ready()` выполняется асинхронно